# Transfer many files from android to pc, without usb and wifi

Tags: bluetooth, file-transfer

**How can I quickly transfer many files from my Android device to the PC,
without USB cable or WiFi?**

Regular bluetooth would require to transfer every single file manually.

Comment: Bluetooth is still fairly slow.  An ad-hoc Wi-Fi solution might be better, it doesn't require a router, though I am not sure what that would require on the PC side.

Comment: @Matthew I can bet, Bluetooth is faster than practical speed of ad-hoc or normal wi-fi on Android device. I don't know if you still live in Bluetooth 2.1 world..

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 How fast (Bluetooth) did you notice?

Answer (score 5):

Install [Astro File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro) with [Astro Bluetooth Module](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro.network.bluetooth). Go to Networks page of Astro File Manager (using toolbar) and tap Bluetooth icon. On next screen, turn on Bluetooth and check `OBEX FTP Server`.

After pairing, use Bluetooth software on PC to browse file system of device (almost all software work as OBEX FTP client). You can copy an entire folder from device to PC. Done!

Comment: thanks for your reply. what software do you suggest to use on windows 7 ? :)

Comment: Haven't you already got Bluetooth software with its driver (using which you pair devices)? That software should work as client.. Explore that..

Comment: Windows 7 has a built-in bluetooth stack and software. It should be sufficient to meet your needs.

Comment: Or, try this: http://www.windows7download.com/win7-bluetooth-file-transfer/vpylckzn.html

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to muck about wirelessly, why not just take the SD card out of your phone and insert it into your PC?  You can then fiddle with files to your heart's content.

Comment: That would require a card reader and he may not a removable card. Thought it's far easier than bluetooth.

Comment: thanks, but this solution is not so practical, since I would have to shut the phone down.

Comment: @iAsk What's impractical about that?  Are you transferring all these files repeatedly?  You also shouldn't have to shut it down, you can just dismount the card in Settings.

Comment: I have to remove the battery

Answer (score 0):

Open Bluetooth settings, go to Shared Folder tab, check box for 'Allow remote devices to change content of shared folder'. Enjoy ridiculously fast file sharing.

Comment: This is seemingly not a standard Android function. I bet it's tied to one manufacturer. What phone are you using? Samsung?

Answer (score 0):

While a good bluetooth app is probably your best bet, I can think of 2 other ways that answer the question:

1. NFC. Probably slower than bluetooth, and you'd require a special module to use it with a PC--even if you can find a phone that has it.
2. Network your phone with an OTG ethernet adapter. Though in most cases if you don't want a USB cable you don't want this. It can be useful in cases where you don't have physical access to the USB port of a PC, but you can use e.g. FTP file transfer over the network.

Answer (score 0):

Shareit application can be used for the transfer of files from PC to Mobile and viceversa

It does not require wifi or cables. It Would create a hotspot(have to create a network in mobile and suggested to turn off your mobile data) then you can transfer from PC to Mobile and vice versa.

(Make it as a comment as i dont have enough reputations)